# Smart way of patching updated properties on Objects in Java

Tags: java

So I was wondering if there is a simple clean not too much boiler plated solution to update an Object in java. So here is basically what I would like to achieve and the alternate solution which I can make work, but which is a bit cumbersome/tedious in my opinion:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private Integer age;

    //Wanted solution
    public void patchUser(User otherUser) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException {
        for (Field field : Class.forName(User.class.getName()).getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(otherUser) != null) {
                this.field = field;
            }
        }
    }

    //Alternate working solution
    public void patchUser2(User otherUser) {
        if (!this.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(otherUser.getName())) {
            this.setName(otherUser.getName());
        }

        if (!this.getAddress().equals(otherUser.getAddress())) {
            this.setAddress(otherUser.getAddress());
        }

        //... etc.
    }

}
```

So the first `patchUser(...)` method is what I would like to achieve if that is possible somehow I cannot seem to figure it out. It would be nice if I added a new field to my User then this field would automatically be taken care of in the first option whereas in the second solution I would have to remember to add the check for the field manually.

**Edit 1** So what I am looking for is if I have given to User objects:

```
OldUserObject {
   "name": "John",
   "Address": {
      "Street": "Avenue 1"
   },
   "phoneNumber": "12345678",
   "age": 37      
}

NewUserObject {
       "name": "Peter",
       "Address": null,
       "phoneNumber": "12345679",
       "age": null      
    }
```

So the `OldUserObject` is what I have when the user signed up now he wants to change some information about himself so I receive a new object and based on what the user wants to change I only get the values for those fields he/she wants to change, the other fields might be null as illustrated in the above example, and if they are so or if they are unchanged they should not be updated on the old object so I would end up with a object as such:

```
OldUserObject {
       "name": "Peter",
       "Address": {
          "Street": "Avenue 1"
       },
       "phoneNumber": "12345679",
       "age": 37      
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking to clone the user? If so you the `clone()` method.

Comment: `field.set(this, field.get(otherUser))` only for non-primitive fields

Comment: @anchreg no I am looking to update a field, lets say that the user changes name from John to Peter then I would like to update that on the old object, but he has not changed the address, therefore the address I received on the new object is null, so I should not update the address field.

Comment: You only have four attribute. Why don't you go with a simple `Optional.ofNullable(other.name).ifPresent(this::setName)` (not sure about the syntax). PS On the first one, you check for null, on the second one, you check for equality. So this seems obvious one is more "complex".

Comment: @AxelH this is just an example, in reality, I have a Bean with ~20 properties now if I would have to add a new property I would also have to add a new Optional, but this might be the way also to keep it simple, thanks for the suggestion I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for an "improved" second way.
The use of `Optional` to keep something clean and quite straight forward :

```
class Test{
    private String s;
    private int i;

    public Test(String s, int i){
        this.s = s;
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void patchTest(Test t){
        Optional.ofNullable(t.s).ifPresent(this::setS);
        Optional.ofNullable(t.i).ifPresent(this::setI);
    }

    //setter setS and setI
}
```

Now, this is a simple example, but a mapping could be use to execute this in a more generic way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion AxelH I have a look at it and try it out :)

Comment: This solution will be verbose but give you more control @Yantes . What do you want to do with primitive, with collections. Here the example is not perfect because we only use primitive and immutable class. What about a mutable class, do you want to use the same reference (so changing the value in `a` impact `b`) ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by primitives, I am using reference types. Yeah, basically the value in reference `a` should impact the value in reference `b` as long as it is not null.

Comment: What I mean @yantes is that if you have a `List` in `A` and you simply `B.setList(A.getList())`, any update on one instance list will be done on the other (same instance, same reference). This will not be the case with primitive type (int, short, boolean) or immutable instance like ( String ). So if you don't define the depth of the copy, it won't be answerable more.